# How do you put multiple images in a different position between texts?

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, responsive, responsive-images

I am new to CSS, and I'm planning to make a page section where there are four images (two left, two right) between a text and each image is located on a different position. I need to make it responsive, meaning that when using phone, two of the images will be hidden.

I'm using Bootstrap. I decided to use row and col, but I am lost what to do afterwards.

I'm trying to make it based on the figure below:

**Desktop View**

[image]

**Mobile View**

[image]

Is it possible to create this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: **Yes**, this is possible to create and has many ways to achieve. But you need to have tried by yourself,  this case is about *CSS Layout* so deep into the keyword will help to indicate solutions. We help you, not do it for you. You might take a look at [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Comment: Hello, I've been learning CSS for some time and I am still learning some ways to execute the design. Thank you so much for letting me know!